# How to call an api at the end of all feature files in karate DSL

Tags: karate

I have a scenario in which I would like to invoke an api at the end of all features execution to clean up the data.
Currently I have the parallel runner being implemented and would like to add this clean up api step at the end of execution of all the features.
Please let me know.

Thanks